# Vertical Timeline keep events title hidden on untill user click year button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeline

I need a timeline script that can show years in vertical formation.

I came across one which is fine but i am not able to hide the actual events under each years by default or either keep events for current or last year open.

I have setup example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axRSC/2/)

Actual example is here https://github.com/technotarek/timeliner.

I want to do following with script

1. Make only Timeline years visible and when one click on the years it shows up events for that year.
2. I want to change the animation as slide from top as that might look nice.

I will also try further to see if i can do something about it any help in this regard is highly appreciate.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="timelineContainer" id="timelineContainer">
      <div class="timelineToggle">
        <p><a class="expandAll">+ expand all</a></p>
      </div><br class="clear">

      <div class="timelineMajor">
        <h2 class="timelineMajorMarker"><span>1954</span></h2>

        <dl class="timelineMinor">
          <dt id="19540517"><a>Brown v. Board of Education</a></dt>

          <dd class="timelineEvent" id="19540517EX" style="display:none;">
            <h3>May 17, 1954</h3>

            <p>The U.S. Supreme Court hands down a unanimous 9-0 decision in
            the Brown v. Board of Education of Topeka case, opening the door
            for the civil rights movement and ultimately racial integration in
            all aspects of U.S. society. In overturning Plessy v. Ferguson
            (1896), the court rules that “separate educational facilities are
            inherently unequal.”<sup>1</sup></p><br class="clear">
          </dd><!-- /.timelineEvent -->
        </dl><!-- /.timelineMinor -->
      </div><!-- /.timelineMajor -->


      <br class="clear">
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->

  <div class="container">
  </div>&gt;<!-- /.container -->
```

This is how i want it..

[image: Timeline of years]

**UPDATE**: 
I managed to make it work to some extend but still need to be fixed further like it show all event for year click as open which it should not show details of event unless i click on the event.. and when one clicks on the event years it should then hide all its event again 
my latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/axRSC/6/
I managed to pull it this far but still need to fix above concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 :: **Starting state of info** ::

Modify your initializer as follows:

```
    $.timeliner({
        startState: 'closed'
    });
```

2 :: **Slide animation** ::

Modify `openEvent()` and `closeEvent` functions in **timeliner.js** as follows:

```
    function openEvent(eventHeading,eventBody) {
        $(eventHeading)
            .removeClass('closed')
            .addClass('open')
            .animate({ fontSize: settings.fontOpen }, settings.baseSpeed);
        $(eventBody).slideDown(settings.speed*settings.baseSpeed); // <-- slideDown
    }

    function closeEvent(eventHeading,eventBody) {
        $(eventHeading)
            .animate({ fontSize: settings.fontClosed }, 0)
            .removeClass('open')
            .addClass('closed');
        $(eventBody).slideUp(settings.speed*settings.baseSpeed); // <-- slideUp
    }
```

**:: UPDATE 3 ::**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/axRSC/8/)**

Comment: I tried but it didn't not work on my local machine. I followed the instruction but it still keeps all event under each year and shows first event open by default

Comment: I can manually hide `<dl class="timelineMinor" style="display:none;">...</dl>` by adding css to it as `style="display:none;"` this will hide all the event but then i need to show them when one click on the particulate years or on a link which show all event title only not contents..

Comment: I will provide fiddle. One sec.

Comment: Appreciate, But i want to hide all event under each year.. I ave update question with the image that will give you a clear idea of what i am trying to do...

Comment: I managed to make it work to some extend but still need to be fixed further like it show all event for year click as open which it should not show details of event unless i click on th event.. http://jsfiddle.net/axRSC/6/

Comment: Thanks you also did it using script but it show all the event open for that year how can we change it further to show only that even which we click on.

Comment: Great appreciate your solution. Can you please also update answer section as this can be very useful to other guys also. I will mark it as correct answer as it works  fine..

Comment: Please select as correct answer if you are satisfied =D